# I would like to know how to integrate Nginx in the Windows Laravel project

Tags: nginx

I would like to know how to integrate Nginx in the Windows Laravel project.

I tried by modifying the server block column in the Nginx conf file, but it didn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVfw7.png)

I am working on opening a domain through a host by linking Laravel and Nginx locally, and I would like to know how to solve it. help.